# How to maximize objective function $z=xy$ where $x$ and $y$ can take only integer values

Tags: optimization, algorithms, integer-programming, discrete-optimization

I want to maximize the value of product of $x$ and $y$ where $x$ and $y$ can take only integer values as well as there are some constraints as mentioned below :

$$x+\alpha y \le N \textrm{ and } x>0,\  y>0$$

where $\alpha$ and $N$ are known constants and could be very large.
How to solve such a problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function
$$f(y):=y(N-\alpha y)={N^2\over 4\alpha}-\alpha\left(y-{N\over2\alpha}\right)^2$$
is unimodal and takes its maximum at $y_*:={N\over2\alpha}$. The optimal integer value of $y$ therefore is one of $\lfloor y_*\rfloor$ and $\lceil y_*\rceil$.

(*Unimodal* means: increasing till the max, then decreasing.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $f=xy$ when $x>0,y>0$ $f$ is a increment function and symmetric to the plain $x-y=0$. The condition $x+\alpha y \leq N$ implies that the range of points (x,y) are below the line $x+\alpha y = N$. So now, the range is a triangular. Now it is only have to consider the edge of triangular. It obvious that the two sides x=0 and y=0 is not a maximum value,so we need to take third edge. Replacing x in $f=xy$ by $x+\alpha y=N$  we have

$f=y(N-\alpha y)$.

so it is easy to find the max value of this parabola.

Comment: The problem with this approach is its valid for continuous function but as i stated before x and y can only take integer values. hence we cannot take derivate of f=y(N-alpha*y) and equate = 0 to get the critical points since these critical points may be non integers

Comment: yes, you are right about that ,but if you choose  those two integer points near the  $\frac{N}{2\alpha}$, and compare them to find the largest one. Note that every time we choose a integer point for $y$, we have a integer point for $x$.

Comment: any fast way to find integer points in neighbourhood rather than hit and trial?